# How to properly keep logs of Spring Boot JMS app deployed in a Linux server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jenkins, spring-jms

I have created a Spring Boot JMS application. It's function is to act as middleware which consumes/listens messages (xml) from a SOURCE system, transforms the xml, sends the transformed xml to a DESTINATION system.

I have already deployed the jar file in a Linux server. This is the first time I deployed an application, I am not sure of the correct way of keeping a history of log to a file should any error occur while the spring boot app is consuming and processing XML messages.

Some of the XML messages contain account numbers and if anything fails, I need to have some way of knowing which account failed.

I'm unsure because when working in the IDE, when you run the spring boot application, we normally see in the console a log of what is happening. But after I deployed the jar to the Linux server, I no longer have an IDE console to see what's happening. I just see the jar application running in port 8080.

In the IDE, normally we output messages using `LOGGER.info()`, `LOGGER.error()`...

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeClassFile.class);
```

What would be the best approach to keep history of logs?

Possible scenarios would be failure in connection while consuming messages from SOURCE system OR while sending messages to DESTINATION system.
Another possible failure would be, failure to transform XML messages.
All of that needs to be captured.

I deployed the app by creating a simple jenkins task which copies the jar to the Linux server after building.

I'd appreciate any comment or suggestion.

Thank you.

Comment: It also logs to a file already, if you are using the defaults. It will rotate daily.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your comment, it helped me find the resource page here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging.file-output